# $\sigma$-ring generated by $\delta$-ring

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ by non empty and $D$ a $\delta$-ring.
I must prove the set:

$$\sigma(D)=\{A:\exists(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}\subset D \hspace{0.2cm} s.t\hspace{0.2cm} A=\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} A_{i}\}\tag{1} $$
is the $\sigma$-ring  generated by $D$. To do that, I need to prove: (1): $D\subset \sigma(D) $; (2): $\sigma(D)$ is a *ring* ; (3): $\forall (S_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset\sigma(D)\hspace{0.4cm}\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} S_{i}\in\sigma(D)$.

I can prove (1) and (2) but (3) is the problem. I've tried to construct sequence: $S_n=\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} A_{i}^{n}$ and then $\bigcup S_n=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}A_{i}^{n}$  and if I can write this like a single union of set's from $D$, I will be done. 
(Edit) And to complete I need to prove $\sigma(D)$ 
is the smallest in the sense of inclusion but I don't know how.

Comment: You probably mean that all $A_n \in D$ too in the first equation.

Comment: It's clear that if $\sigma(D)$ as defined is a $\sigma$-ring that contains $D$ (as (1),(2) and (3) together state) it must be minimally such, as the formation operation (taking unions of sequences) is one that all $\sigma$-rings are closed under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3 you *are* done, because it's easy to write a countable union of countable unions as a single countable union by reindexing (using some bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$, of which there are plenty).

Minimality is clear: if $\mathcal{S}$ is *any* $\sigma$-ring that contains $D$, $\sigma(D)$ as defined by your first formula is a subset of $\mathcal{S}$. So it must be the minimal $\sigma$-ring generated by $D$ which justifies the notation.

Comment: i can make a matrix with the terms of the sequence $A_i^n$, and consider union of all the terms from a diagonal is a new term . in other words construct the sequence:$A_0^0\cup ( A_0^1\cup A_1^0) \cup (A_2^0 \cup A_1^1 \cup A_0^2)...$

Comment: @IcaSandu no need to construct a new sequence of sets. Just reindex the ones you have.

Comment: ok the ideea : reindex using a bijection . i can understand that thanks!